# I cannot use spacy or load any language models

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

OS: MacOs

software: PyCharm

Spacy version: 3.4.2

Python version   3.10.0

I'm having a problem with the Spacy package which is I cannot use it at all, I can't load any of the language models. the download is always successful but I can't use/import it at all.

```py
import spacy

nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

or

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

or

```
nlp = spacy.load(r'DIRECTORY PATH CONTAINING THE PACKAGE')
```

or

```
import spacy.cli 
spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_md')
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

None of these worked with me always giving this error

[image: Error 1]

after trying multiple solutions from posts here  whatever I do I always get this error

[[image: error 2error3]

I'm really stuck and I ran out of solutions...

Comment: Have you tried to download it from the terminal? `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Comment: have you installed the model package via pip? `pip install en_core_web_md `

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano yes I did. the downloading is always successful

Comment: @BijayRegmi yes I did but I get this error  [  ImportError: cannot import name 'get_torch_default_device' from 'thinc.api' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/api.py)
]

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/6368

Comment: yeah I visited this post but the original poster had a different error than mine. nevertheless I have uninstall ' thing' then reinstall it but I get the same and honestly im not sure how 'thinc' is linked to spacy?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed `spacy` and the models in the same environement.

Check with `pip list` and `pip3 list` and install the `en-core-web-sm` accordingly.